# Is there a way to fix the code to check if a textbox or combobox is empty?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to check if the user has completed all Text, ComboBoxes. At the moment it works, but not well as it brings up the msgbox after every non completed and every completed box.

I have tried the code below and I have moved the location of the MsgBox

```
Sub CheckEmpty()

Dim ctrlT As Object
Dim ctrlC As Object

For Each ctrlT In Me.Controls
If TypeName(ctrlT) = "TextBox" Then
    If ctrlT.Value = Empty Then
        ctrlT.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
End If
MsgBox "Please complete all missing information"
Next ctrlT

For Each ctrlC In Me.Controls
If TypeName(ctrlC) = "ComboBox" Then
    If ctrlC.Value = Empty Then
        ctrlC.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
End If
MsgBox "Please complete all missing information"
Next ctrlC

End Sub
```

Please assist with improved code that will make all Text and ComboBoxes red if their not completed and bring up one msgbox that says it needs to be completed.

It should also not give a msgbox if all is completed, which it currently does....

Comment: You have your MsgBox within the `For Each` loop. Maybe have a boolean variable to remember if any combobox hasn't got text and test that variable after your loop.

Comment: I have moved it outside, but still get the mesgbox even if all boxes are completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you want to do something with the data after `CheckEmpty()` so that calling code needs to know the result of the test to decide if it should continue -  `CheckEmpty()` should probably be a function.

```
Sub Test()

    If (Not CheckEmpty()) Then
        '// come controls were empty
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox "do work"
End Sub

Function CheckEmpty() As Boolean

    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim gotError As Boolean

    '// loop controls, all empty ones are red otherwise they are reset to white
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.ComboBox Or TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
            If ctrl.Value = Empty Then
                gotError = True
                ctrl.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Else
                ctrl.BackColor = vbWindowBackground
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl

    If (gotError) Then MsgBox "Please complete all missing information"

    CheckEmpty = Not gotError
End Function
```